# Using WinSCP .NET assembly in SSIS to retrieve list of files

Tags: c#, ssis, ftp, winscp

I am trying to get the list files from FTP using WinSCP assemblies, but I am getting some exceptions in the below code, in fact the connection itself is not getting established

I created a breakpoint in the very first line and it is throwing this exception in the very first line itself.

Code:

```
SessionOptions sessionoptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "<FTP Name>",
    UserName = "<FTP User Name>",
    Password = "<FTP Password>"
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionoptions);

    RemoteDirectoryInfo directory = session.ListDirectory("/<Folder Location>");

    List<String> filelist = new List<string>();

    foreach (RemoteFileInfo remotefileinfo in directory.Files)
    {
        filelist.Add(remotefileinfo.Name);
    }

    string line = string.Join(",", filelist.ToArray());

    MessageBox.Show(line);
}
```

Exception:

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

PS: I am new to C# and WinSCP

Comment: You didn't include the exception message. What statement/line does throw? (please edit your question)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have updated the question !! please check this out !!

Comment: 1) You still didn't include the exception text! 2) So it does throw on `SessionOptions sessionoptions = new SessionOptions`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl 1) I tried using a Try and Catch block and then catch the exception text but still this (the one in the question) is what I am getting. 2) Yes it does throw there only.

Comment: 1) Can you include a screenshot or something?

Comment: Did you add a project reference to the WinSCP assembly?  Also, if you're using it in SSIS, you need to register the assembly in the GAC.

Comment: @sorrell That's also true. This is documented here: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#gac

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Looks like I didn't do it, but still I tried to register the assembly in the GAC using the new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish().GACInstall("<Location>\<Assemblyname>.dll"); but even this is not helping me.

Comment: 1) Again, can you include a screenshot (or something) of the exception? 2) Where are you registering the assembly from?

Comment: 1.) Sorry I am not having enough reputation to do that :( 2.) I am registering the Assembly from my local only (C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll)

Comment: 1) Just upload it somewhere a share a link here. 2) But where do you run the `GACInstall` code from?

Comment: 1.) working on it 2.) Created a SSIS script in a package in the same system(where i have my Assembly installed) and ran it from there

Comment: Finally I am able to run the code successfully after registering the assembly in GAC, but the Script task is getting completed by this line  RemoteDirectoryInfo directory = session.ListDirectory("/<Folder Location>");

Comment: Ok Got it !! Thanks a lot to @MartinPrikryl for your timely helps !!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me break down the solution for the issue that I faced, basically I wanted to download the list of files available in the FTP Server

1. Download the WinSCP assembly files from this location http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install
2. Create a SSIS Script task and the copy paste the above code in it.
3. Add the assembly as a reference to do that

   Go To -> Project -> Add Reference -> Browse (Browse and add the dll file here)
4. To access this assembly from SSIS this assembly needs to be registered in GAC.

   Open Power shell and type in the following commands

   ```
   Set-Alias

   Name:Gacutil

   Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe

   Gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"
   ```

   This would register the assembly in GAC. Now the SSIS script task should execute without any issue.

Comment: To register the assembly in GAC, you can use the `gacutil.exe` directly. Running PowerShell console and creating an alias for one-off use is overkill. See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#gac

Comment: Also of note, you should register the assembly in the GAC before opening Visual Studio, or restart VS after registering.